# Prevent multiple click event triggering on scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

am trying to trigger a click event on scroll. Like left navigation on scrolling top and right navigation on scrolling down , am trying to achieve it by

```
$('#elem').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
     if(e.delta < 0) {
         //scroll left
         $(".left-nav").trigger("click");
     }else {
         //scroll right
         $(".left-nav").trigger("click");
     }
     return false;
 });
```

but the click event is triggered multiple times . Please help me in getting the click event triggered only once regardless of the scroll speed .

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle.net?  and you only want to trigger click once?  or once within a certain period of time?

Comment: Your `if` and `else` statemet do the same. Is it the expected?

Comment: no thats typo mistake. It should be left-nav and right-nav.i want to trigger it only once

Answer (score 0):

That's because the scroll event is fired continuously.  So if you roll your mouse wheel then stop, that does not equal one event.  Try putting a `console.log("mouse scrolled")` in your mousewheel handler, you'll see what I mean pretty quickly.

You're going to need to compromise in one way or another to accomplish what you're attempting.  I'd suggest using `setTimeout` in your handler and triggering the `click` event after the timeout duration (in the `setTimeout` callback).  If a second scroll event comes in before the first expires, cancel the first and restart it.  This would be the equivalent of user scrolling, then stopping scrolling...then you trigger `click`.

*-- Edit --*

Here's an opposite approch - trigger the click on the first mousewheel event you capture, then ignore the rest until the user stops scrolling for at least `n` milliseconds, say, 500.  Might look roughly (meaning "untested") like...

```
var scrolled = false,
    scrollTimeout;

$('#elem').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
    // absorb scroll
    e.preventDefault();

    // Scrolled yet?
    if(!scrolled){
        // Note they've scrolled
        scrolled = true;
        // Click appropriate nav
        $(e.delta < 0 ? '.left-nav' : '.right-nav').trigger("click");
    }

    // Reset the timer
    clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);

    // If the user stops scrolling for 500 millis, they can trigger click w/ next scroll
    scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        scrolled = false;
    }, 500);
}
```

Cheers

Comment: hey Madbreaks. its not working it is triggering the click event only once . ;(

Comment: I updated my answer.  Give that a try.  If it doesn't work, create a jsfiddle and I'll look at it.  What browser?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var busy = false;
$('#elem').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
    if (!busy) {
        busy = true;
        if(e.delta < 0) {
           //scroll left
           $(".left-nav").trigger("click");
        } else {
           //scroll right
           $(".left-nav").trigger("click");
        }
    }
 return false;
 });
```

Then put 'busy' to 'false' when your click function is finished

Comment: This permanently disables the nav functionality after one click.  Doubt that's what op is after.